# Finite difference approximation, convergence in $L^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Consider a sequence of functions $(q_{\eta})_{\eta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}}\subseteq L^{1}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}_{\geq0})$ so that there exists $q^{*}\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}):\ q_{\eta}\rightarrow q^{*} \text{ in } L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ for $\eta\rightarrow 0$. Assume in addition that there exists $C\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}:\ \sup_{\eta\in\mathbb{R}}|q_{\eta}|_{TV(\mathbb{R})}\leq C$. Then, we want to show the following:

For $\phi\in C^{1}_{\text{c}}(\mathbb{R})$ assume that the sequence
\begin{align}
    \tfrac{1}{2\eta} \int_{\mathbb{R}} q_{\eta}(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)-q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\phi(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)+q_{\eta}(x)+q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\mathrm{d} x \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\end{align}
converges for $\eta\rightarrow 0$ to $-\int_{\mathbb{R}} (q^{*}(x))^3\phi_{x}(x)\;\mathrm{d} x,$ i.e. $$
    \lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\tfrac{1}{2\eta} \int_{\mathbb{R}} q_{\eta}(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)-q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\phi(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)+q_{\eta}(x)+q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\mathrm{d} x\\=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} (q^{*}(x))^{3}\phi'(x)\;\mathrm{d} x,\label{eq:2} \tag{2}
$$
can we say anything about the convergence of \ref{eq:1} when leaving out one of the terms in the fourth factor, i.e. can we say anything about the convergence of$$
\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\tfrac{1}{2\eta} \int_{\mathbb{R}} q_{\eta}(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)-q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\phi(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)+q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\mathrm{d} x=??
$$
Clearly, the right candidate for the convergence would presumably be (compare to \ref{eq:2}) $-\tfrac{2}{3} \int_{\mathbb{R}}(q^{*}(x))^{3}\phi'(x)\;\mathrm{d} x$ however, we fail to show this.

The problem can also be interpreted as a question about convergence of finite difference approximations of derivatives as the second factor in \ref{eq:1}, $\tfrac{q_{\eta}(x+\eta)-q_{\eta}(x-\eta)}{2\eta}$ can be seen as the approximation of $q_{\eta}'(x)$ (which might in our setting exist for $\eta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ but which does NOT exist for $\eta\rightarrow 0$ or only in a measure sense).

EDIT: For a simplified version of this question see [Finite difference approximations of serivatives of polynomials of BV functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323135/finite-difference-approximations-of-derivatives-of-polynomials-of-bv-functions)

Comment: Could you provide some insight into the convergence assumption? On first inspection, I would expect the integral to converge, if at all, to $$-2\int_{\mathbb{R}} (q^{*}(x))^{3}\phi'(x)\;\mathrm{d} x;$$ perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @R_B: Thanks for asking. Almost. Assuming that $q_{\eta}$ is smooth also in the limit, the integral would actually converge to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} 2*(q^{*}(x))^{2}q^{*}_{x}(x) \phi(x)\mathrm{d} x$ so that one can shift the derivative to the test function $\phi$ to obtain as limit point $1/3$ multiplied with the term you gave. So in case you were wondering about the missing minus sign, you are right, I have changed it.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I was referring to integral (1). Assuming enough properties of the family $q_\eta$:
\begin{align}
&
\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}
\frac{1}{\eta} \int q_{\eta}(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)-q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)\phi(x)\Big(q_{\eta}(x+\eta)+q_{\eta}(x)+q_{\eta}(x-\eta)\Big)dx
,\\= &
\int
q(x)
\Big(2q'(x)\Big)
\phi(x)
\Big(3q(x)\Big)
dx
,\\= &
2
\int
3q^2(x)
q'(x)
\phi(x)
dx
,\\= &
2
\int
\Big(q^3(x)\Big)'
\phi(x)
dx
,\\= &
-2
\int
q^3(x)
\phi(x)'
dx
.
\end{align}
(By $q$ I mean $q^*$).

Comment: @R_B: Sorry, you are absolutely right. I had forgotten the 2 in the denominator. Now, it should be correct, finally. Sorry for the confusion!