# Finite difference approximations of derivatives of polynomials of BV functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation, finite-differences

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ and $\phi\in C^{1}_{\text{c}}(\mathbb{R})$ be given and assume that $q\in BV(\mathbb{R})$. Then, we are wondering if the following **finite difference approximation** holds:
$$
\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0} \tfrac{n}{2\eta}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big(q(x+\eta)-q(x-\eta)\big)\big(q(x)\big)^{n-1}\phi(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big(q(x)\big)^{n}\phi'(x)\;\mathrm{d} x.
$$
For $n\in\{1,2\}$ this is true and can be shown by moving the shift in $\eta$ onto the test function $\phi$. Does this also hold for $n>2$?

Note that this question is a simplified version of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315501/finite-difference-approximation-convergence-in-l1) where we assume that $q$ itself cannot change with respect to $\eta$.

Comment: I guess the simplistic answer is Yes.  You are just doing integration by parts and switching the limit and integration operator. (I'm assuming that $C^1_c(\mathbb R)$ means compactly supported functions with continuous derivatives.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false.

Choose any $b>a>0$. Define $q$ as

$$q(x)=\begin{cases}0,x\in(-\infty,0)\cup[2,\infty)\\a,x\in[0,1)\\b,x\in[1,2)\end{cases}$$

Take $\phi$ as any function in $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ that is $1$ on $[0,2]$ and $0$ outside $(-1,3)$.

Assuming the conjecture is true, we should have

$$\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\eta}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(q(x+\eta)-q(x-\eta))q(x)^{n-1}dx=0$$

However, the result is $a\cdot a^{n-1}+(b-a)\cdot(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})-b\cdot b^{n-1}=a^{n-1}b-ab^{n-1}\neq 0$.